# Detect whether file is an image

Tags: php, image, file-upload, upload

I a have a code to upload images to my server however before uploading the image  the code checks whether the uploaded file is an image by checking its extension (allowed extensions are "jpg", "png" and "gif"), however I just realized that this isn't secure enough because I could  easily create a "file.php" and rename it "file.png" and then the code wouldn't prevent file to be uploaded. Is there an alternative way to detect weather the file is an image?

UPDATE: I am using $_FILES to get the images.

Comment: There is no 100% reliable way; just don't execute .png files with php (or: only execute code you 100% trust).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, you can do this:

```
$image = "myImage.jpg";// the path to the file name

$res = getimagesize($image);

if($res === true)
{
 // this is an image
}
```

`getimagesize()` is a function to get info of an image. If the given filename is not an image, then it returns false, else it returns an array of image's info such as width and height.

If you want to check the image which is in `$_FILES` super array, then the following code should be used:

```
getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])
```

I assume your file input is named "file"

Comment: When used this function getimagesize($_Files["name"]"tmp_name") I get Warning: getimagesize(1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in index.php on line 40

Comment: because the address you pass to the function is incorrect. It has nothing to do with the function, the URL to the file is not correct so that PHP cannot find the image and throws an error.

Comment: what is the correct url then for $_FILES

Comment: wait to update the answer

Comment: The code works but when I created a jpg file with text "dsvsd" or "" I get error getimagesize(): Read error!

Comment: You have to use `error_reporting(E_ERROR)` to avoid getting errors for `NOTICE` level.
If it works then you can accept this as an answer.

Comment: I would not count on a clever attacker not being able to fool `getimagesize()` in returning some value, while the file still contains some valid PHP code. This function was *not* designed as a secure image validation function!

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use `getimagesize()`.

It returns zeros for sizes on non-images.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check like this `$_FILES['file_upload']['type']`

Example:

```
 if($_FILES['file_upload']['type'] != 'image/png'){
       //message to inform the user
 }
```

Comment: I think that's coming from the browser though.